# How to deploy apps in IBM SmartCloud for Social Business

Tags: ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I cannot seem to find any documentation on how to register/deploy an application into my IBM Social Business SmartCloud site.  This is on their cloud servers not an my own on premise localhost.

I created an Admin + AppDeveloper user account with a IBM SmartCloud Engage Demonstration Account subscription. I'm basically trying to add the HelloWorld iWidget to one of the App menus and cannot find where to register/add so I can include it to the top apps menu of the site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@David - you cannot install iWidgets into the SmartCloud for Social Business.  We currently do not support installing 3rd party gadgets or iWidgets into the platform.

You may want to look at this presentation which outlines organizational extensions.  Organizational Extensions are loose coupling between the view in the platform and the partner application

http://www.slideshare.net/paulbastide/business-partner-day-406-ignite-your-ibm-social-business-ap